# Find time taken between start and end pattern in context

Tags: esper

Im trying to create a pattern which is triggered by having at least 100 events within 1 minutes over 10 minutes.

This is what I have:

```
create context C
start pattern[every ( [10] ( [100](Enter) )where timer:within(60sec))]
end pattern[every (timer:interval(120sec) and not S)];
```

How do I get the start and end time of the context? It context.startTime works, but context.endTime returns null. I need to compute the time of the start pattern and the end pattern.

Thanks

Comment: "current_timestamp" gives you the current time. Context end time is a value that is computed at start and for patterns its not available.

Comment: Ok but when i select current_timestamp from my stream it doesn't return anything. Could you provide an example with a query using the context using current_timestamp?

Comment: Nvm got i working. Thanks.